# How to load in array of events to fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, arrays, date, fullcalendar

I am custom building an array of events to populate the calendar display with but seem to be unable to get it to display at all. I think it is around the date formatting.

My event object I am creating has a series of date parameters that are constructed into a date string as follows:

```
eventArray[i].end  = eventArray[i].endYear + '-' + eventArray[i].endMonth + '-' + eventArray[i].endDay  + ' ' + eventArray[i].endHours + ':' + eventArray[i].endMins + ':' + eventArray[i].endSecs;
console.log(eventArray[i].end);
eventArray[i].start = eventArray[i].startYear + '-' + eventArray[i].startMonth + '-' + eventArray[i].startDay  + ' ' + eventArray[i].startHours + ':' + eventArray[i].startMins + ':' + eventArray[i].startSecs;
console.log(eventArray[i].start);
```

The output strings on the console log are (for example)

```
2014-2-11 22:0:0
2014-2-11 21:0:0
```

When I then do a console.log of the actual object from the array however I get the date strings suddenly reformatted as

```
end: Tue Feb 11 2014 22:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)
__proto__: Invalid Date
```

which is the output in the Chrome dev console.

Any ideas as to (a) why this is getting automatically formatted as an invalid date and (b) how I could go about fixing this to be a valid object? A complete console show of the same object is also below if it helps.

```
_end: Tue Feb 11 2014 22:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)
_id: "someIDString"
_start: Tue Feb 11 2014 21:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)
allDay: true
className: Array[0]
color: "#66CC66"
end: Tue Feb 11 2014 22:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)
endDay: "11"
endHours: "22"
endMins: "0"
endMonth: "2"
endSecs: "0"
endYear: "2014"
id: "00Ub00000038hA6EAI"
source: Object
start: Tue Feb 11 2014 21:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)
startDay: "11"
startHours: "21"
startMins: "0"
startMonth: "2"
startSecs: "0"
startYear: "2014"
title: "Desk Booking"
```

Comment: hum i think you have your problem right there 2014-2-11 22:0:0
2014-2-11 21:0:0 try to add "hard coded" an event to the array but with start and end date like this 2014-02-11 22:00:00
2014-02-11 21:00:00, and see if its loaded.

Answer (score 0):

So I resolved this by hard coding into my event the allDay parameter to be false. The event now shows properly on the calendar as expected.